# How to support Unicode version 7 in Google Chrome or in Notepad?

Tags: google-chrome, unicode, notepad

currently, I'm working in training Tesseract OCR for Nabataean script language. The problem that I can't display any of Unicode letters for Nabataean that were supported in Unicode Version 7.0. Is there a way to show the letters in Notepad and Google Chrome? 
This is how letters appear in Notepad:

[image: How Alphabet appear in Notepad]

And here is the Unicode for Nabataean alphabet:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabataean_(Unicode_block)

Comment: Did you install a font with the proper glyphs?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams None of the fonts that I found online made the letters appear.

Comment: Time to make your own then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there a way to show the letters in Notepad and Google Chrome?

Yes. Install an appropriate font:

> This is a list of fonts that support characters in the Nabataean
>   Unicode block.
>
> ```
> Font                      Support
> EversonMono                   100% (40 of 40)
> EversonMono-Bold          100% (40 of 40)
> EversonMono-BoldOblique   100% (40 of 40)
> EversonMono-Oblique       100% (40 of 40)
> LastResort                    100% (40 of 40)
> Unifont Upper                 100% (40 of 40)
> ```

Source [Font Support for Unicode Block 'Nabataean'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/nabataean/fontsupport.htm)

Links to fonts:

- http://www.evertype.com/emono/
- https://www.unicode.org/policies/lastresortfont_eula.html
- https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/unifont

Comment: Thank you, I downloaded EversonMono and the letters appear.

Comment: I also installed EversonMono. Selecting the text and setting that font in notepad, it works. Only, I don't manage to see the proper glyphs in Google Chrome: I still see blank squares. Any idea to instruct Chrome to use the proper font?